# Cannot resolve method of android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity in ViewModelProviders

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-architecture-components

I am trying to implement architecture component in my application, but when I am to   add lifecycleowner to my viewmodel inside my fragment with `getActivity()` its show message

> Cannot resolve method of android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity

This is my code:

```
 viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(getActivity()).get(MyViewModel.class);
        viewModel.setToken(token);
        viewModel.getRecent().observe(getActivity(), new Observer<List<Recent>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Recent> recent) {
                adapter.setData(recent);
            }
        });
```

My fragment is derived from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`

and MyActivity is extends `AppCompatActivity`

and this is my Gradle file:

```
    def paging_version = "2.1.0"
    def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"
    def room_version = "2.1.0-alpha04"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.paging:paging-runtime:$paging_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
```

How do I solve this problem? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

In `androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders.of(FragmentActivity)`, they accept `androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity`, not `android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity`.

**Solution**

1. Migrate entire project to AndroidX using `Migrate to AndroidX` which introduced from Android Studio 3.2. You can found information in [this page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)
2. Change dependencies version to support library version. Dependencies version can be found [this page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#pre-androidx_dependencies)

```
dependencies {
    def lifecycle_version = "1.1.1"

    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
    // alternatively - just ViewModel
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:$lifecycle_version" // For Kotlin use viewmodel-ktx
    // alternatively - just LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:$lifecycle_version"
    // alternatively - Lifecycles only (no ViewModel or LiveData).
    //     Support library depends on this lightweight import
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$lifecycle_version"

    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifecycle_version" // For Kotlin use kapt instead of annotationProcessor
    // alternately - if using Java8, use the following instead of compiler
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:$lifecycle_version"

    // optional - ReactiveStreams support for LiveData
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:reactivestreams:$lifecycle_version"

    // optional - Test helpers for LiveData
    testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:$lifecycle_version"
}
```

Comment: @DennyKurniawan 14, same as support library.